# How can i calculate the content of a row in SQL

Tags: oracle, function, count, psql

I started with oracle and right now i need to make a function that can count up the content of a row.

For example i have a database with a row prices and i wanna count up all the prices together

My table name is dbo.products and the row name is prices i have 3 prices in it. How can i count them all together??

i tried something like this:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Vrachtkosten
RETURN NUMBER IS
  Totale_vrachtkosten NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO Totale_vrachtkosten
  FROM Orders;
RETURN Totale_vrachtkosten;
END;
```

Comment: @APC - Is `price1 + price2 + price3` a way to **count** prices? I think not.

Comment: @fiko - it would be helpful for us if you could provide more background about what you are trying to achieve. Some sample data and the desired output is always welcome.